# Binding text label on a home page to a timer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

We have a really simple app, the idea is the timer will update a label on the home screen depending on different configuration within the mobile app. I have created the binding and can update the homepage from it's self but not from the timer. I think what is missing is a OnChange within the home page to detect if the string has changed.

Display layout code, bind the label to the name "LabelText"

```
<Label                
Text = "{Binding LabelText, Mode=TwoWay}"
x:Name="MainPageStatusText"
HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
Grid.Row="2"
Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
TextColor="White"
FontSize="Medium"/>
```

This is the class file to link the text string to the label, I can see it been called from the different places but when it's called from the app.cs it does not work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Binding_Demo
{
    public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e); }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   { OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string labelText;

  public string LabelText
  {
     get {
        return labelText;
        }


    set
        {
           labelText = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("LabelText");

        }
     }
   }  
   }
```

This is the code inside the homepage, this works and I can see it sending data to the text label

```
public static MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
public Homepage()
{

    BindingContext = _myClass;
    _myClass.LabelText = "Inside the home page";

}
```

This is the App.cs code, we start the timer and then want to set the text on the Homepage label. I can see the class been called, but it does not set the text.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Binding_Demo
{
public partial class App : Application
{
public static MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();

public App()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
    {

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer has been triggered");

            // !!!!! This is not setting the text in the label !!!!!
            BindingContext = _myClass;
            _myClass.LabelText = "Inside the timer app";

        });
        return true; //use this to run continuously
    });

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    //

}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // force app to mainpage and clear the token  


}
}
}
```

Comment: HomePage and App appear to both have their own instance of MyClass

Comment: Hi, any updates? If this solution help you to solve the issue, please mark it as the answer. If you are facing some issues while implementing, try to post the particular error with the corresponding codes here.

Comment: How do I close the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created the binding and can update the homepage from it's self but not from the timer.

As Jason said, please make sure the binding model is unique. You could create a global **static** instance of `MyClass` in **App** class, then bind this instance to `HomePage`.

Check the code:

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _myClass.LabelText = "Inside the timer app";
            });
            return true;
        });

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Homepage());
    }
}
```

Homepage.xaml.cs:

```
public Homepage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = App._myClass;
}
```